# Find the probability of getting a heart on the first draw and a club on the second draw while drawing 2 cards successively and without replacement

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations, conditional-probability, poker

I am currently having some difficulty with a card probability question (I guess combinatorics will haunt me for the whole life...).
The question is to find the probability of getting a heart on the first draw and a club on the second draw while drawing 2 cards successively and without replacement from the standard poker deck. There are 2 approaches that I came with but they seem to produce different results.

1. Logically, I believe the answer to be
   $$ 
   P(C|H)=\frac{\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}*\frac{\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{39}{1}}=\frac{1}{12}=0.083
   $$
   However, I can't formally prove that it is the right approach, so I tried using the conditional probability formula.
2. $$ 
   P(C|H)=\frac{P(C\cap H)}{P(H)}=\frac{\binom{13}{1}*\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}/\frac{\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}=\frac{2}{51}=0.0392
   $$

One(or even 2) of my answers are clearly wrong, so I would be glad if someone could tell me where my mistake is and how to fix one(or both) approaches.

Comment: Just speakingy loosely, the probability should be about  $\left(\frac 14\right)^2=\frac 1{16}=.0625$   Speaking more precisely, it is $\frac 14\times \frac {13}{51}=0.06372549$

Comment: Re lulu's comment, once the first card is drawn, (assuming that it is a heart), there are now 51 cards left in the deck, of which 13 are clubs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way to answer this question is to see that the probability of a heart on the first draw is $13/52$, or, equivalently, $1/4$.

Then there are $51$ cards left, so the probability of a spade the next time is $13/51$.

Multiply.

(I haven't addressed your question about what's wrong with your proposed approaches. You don't say why you think either might be right.)

Comment: I believe the first one right as we get the first card, which is a heart from the deck. The next action is to take the 2nd card(a club) out of the remaining 39 cards(excluding 12 remaining hearts). I think should be simillar to the multiplication principle, but I might be wrong. Even if I am correct, I still don't understand where my mistake is for 2)

Comment: @Alex.Kh Why exclude the remaining hearts from the second draw? For the second attempt, what are the events $C$ and $H$ - from what sample space?

Comment: I guess you mean that we have taken only a single card out of the deck, so the denominator must be 51 rather than 39, so this is one mistake on my part for 1). For 2) I considered C and H be events of taking a single club or Heart out of the standard deck of cards.

Comment: @Alex.Kh your second approach is incorrect for two reasons... first... we are not looking for $\Pr(C\mid H)$, we are looking for $\Pr(C\cap H)$, so dividing as you had makes no sense to do.  Second, $C$ here is the event that very specifically the first card is a club, not that either of the cards is a club, and $H$ is for very specifically the second card is a heart.  You calculated in your denominator for your second approach the probability that among the two cards drawn one is a club and one is a heart but it could have been in either order, including the incorrect order.

Comment: @JMoravitz I see, thank you. Just in case, can you please tell me how you would approach $P(C|H)$ (specifically , I mean calculating the probability of getting a club after drawing heart for a 2 card hand)? Your explanation makes perfect sense but I would like to compare it to the $P(C|H)$ calculation to be sure I got it right.

Comment: @Alex.Kh that is just $\frac{13}{51}$ and can be calculated directly.

Comment: @JMoravitz oh yeah... I don't know why I am always looking for the most complicated approach. Thanks again